# Gaps in square tiles layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been struggeling with a layout problem for quite some time now, and I just can't find a solution.

What I am trying to achieve is a square tile layout. With the information I found on Stackoverflow, I've managed to come pretty close, but I can't solve the last piece.

The HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">column big</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">column 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">column 2</div>    
    <div class="col-md-3">column 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">column 4</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">column 5</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">column 6</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">column big</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">column 7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (min-height is placed just for testing):

```
.col-md-6, .col-md-3 {
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
}
.col-md-3 {
    padding-bottom: 25%;
}
```

What happens is that the last column (nr 7) is not placed under column 5 but in a new row. I understand the logic behind it, but it's not what I want.
Tried to solve with Bootstrap, without Bootstrap, with a list, but doesn't work. Also tried several masonry options, but that didn't work either (although that can be because of lack of js-knowledge).

I want the layout to be responsive. Managed to get that working too, except for mentioned problem.

So my question is: is there a way to place 'column 7' where I want it (beneath column 5)?
Can it be done with HTML/CSS? Or do I need javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you pop this into a JSFiddle? You will get better help from the community :)

I doubt the Bootstrap code above will achieve what you want.

Comment: Not really possible with just CSS. You need JS and absolute positioning here. Masonry is a library that does exactly this.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. Just made a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dh070/9n04v2jx/4/. I don't think Bootstrap will solve this. It was just an example of my problem...

Comment: @Sergiu: I tried Masonry (and some others) but couldn't get the result I'm looking for. I got the responsive part working (in Bootstrap and without it), just having the problem with the column...

Comment: You can add margin-top : -315px to column 7 but that won't be a great solution. Just a workaround

Comment: Thank for your reply. I've thought of that, but that would break up the responsive part.

Comment: You can use col-xs-* instead of col-md-*. That will stop your structure from stacking upside down ( I hope that is useful to you. ) and add margin-top : -25% to colomn 7. I have made a bootply for you. Please take a look. http://www.bootply.com/KHNGu9TKTo#

Comment: If you have a fixed layout (exact rows and columns that stay the same regardless of content) then you can go with what @Anuj posted. If not then, as I said, there's no CSS solution, you need JS and Masonry does this.

Comment: @Siddharth: thanks for your effort. But adding the margin-top would break the responsiveness.

Comment: @Sergiu: the layout will be fixed so Anuj's solution is, for me, the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but there are a few things which you should follow:

From the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

> Grid columns are created by specifying the number of twelve available columns you wish to span

This means that the columns in a single row should ideally add up to 12. You can have more, but the documentation also states that extra columns over the 12 limit span will then be pushed onto a new line, which is what you're seeing.

To solve the problem you are seeing, you want to make sure that the columns in a single row only add up to 12. To achieve the result you want, you have to nest rows in columns.

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/28rvh7pd/) for how I've done that (You might need to make the HTML section wider to see your desired result)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 large">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 small">2</div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 small">3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 small">4</div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 small">5</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 small">6</div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 small">7</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 small">8</div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 small">9</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 large">
                10
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.col-md-6 {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
}

.large {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.small {
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Hi Anuj, thanks for your effort. But how can I place a 'large' column on the right with 4 smaller columns left of it? Wouldn't Bootstrap just start on a new row?

Comment: Using the same idea, but just reversing the markup :) See this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/28rvh7pd/2/

Comment: Your solution is working. Thank you so much! I must say that I'm not grasping the idea just yet, but will think it over to fully understand!

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow specific pattern in your html page to apply bootstrap.

css :

```
<style>
    div.big, div.small {
        font-size: -webkit-xxx-large;
    }
    .big {
        padding-bottom: 50%;
        background: #C9A;
    }
    .small {
        padding-bottom: 25%;
        background: #DB2;
    }
</style>
```

html :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 big">column big</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 small">column 1</div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 small">column 2</div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 small">column 3</div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 small">column 4</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 small">column 5</div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 small">column 6</div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 small">column 7</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 big">column big</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your solution is also working. So I would like to thank you as well! Could you please explain why you used two container-fluid and what the font-size: -webkit-xxx-large does? Still learning...

Comment: now it's ok that was place by mistake i did not replace full code with new code thats why there was two container-fluid. And  font-size: -webkit-xxx-large is used to set font size webkit for chrome moz for mozzilla and so on. I just set largest font size for all divs.